# How do I change the value of a key in localStorage inside JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I've got a calendar. Events in the calendar are written as JSON and stored in localStorage like following:

```
   key = events //All events as Object
   value = 
          {
  "Date":"31-3-2015",
  "Event":"Football match", 
  "Participants":"Italy - Germany",
  "Description":"Support our team with your friends!"},

  "Date":"2-4-2015",
  "Event":"First-night play", 
  "Participants":"Famous actors",
  "Description":"Going out to the theatre with my gf"}

  etc...
```

I can also change each line of an event in the calendar. But then I need a new value to be stored in localStorage.

E.g.

```
  //Old version
  ""Date":"2-4-2015",
  "Event":"First-night play", 
  "Participants":"Famous actors",
  "Description":"Going out to the theatre with my gf"}

  //Edited version
  "Date":"2-4-2015",
  "Event":"First-night play", 
  "Participants":"Famous actors",
  "Description":"Let my gf visit the play alone"}
```

Here's my function to add new events or to edit the existing ones:

```
       var addNewEvent = function() {
            var events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events')) || [];

            events.push(
            {Date: storageNewDate, 
             Event: storageEvent, 
             Participants: storageParticipants, 
             Description: storageDescription});

             localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(events)); 
        };
```

But it works only ones for localStorage (if you decide to replace an existing event with new one it won't reset localStorage), though visually you'll see your new event in the calendar cell.

So, how do I refer let's say to "Description" ("Event"? "Participants"?...) in localStorage in my case to re-set the value?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the events array as a string in localStorage. If you want to change any of the values in events, you are going to have to replace the string value stored in the "events" key in localStorage - in other words, replace the entire value of the events array.

Practically, you could extract the values using:

```
events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('events'))
```

change the event you want to change and then save it using:

```
localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(events));
```

If you are thinking about how you could just change the value of a single event in "events" in localStorage, you only have a single key "events", so you can only change that value as a whole.

Comment: When I replace the value by 

localStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(events)); 

it adds one more event in localStorage, but doesn't delete a previous one, then I have two events with the same date in localStorage, though my calendar supposed to have only one event per day.
But user can see only "new" event. So it looks all right, but I'd like to delete a previous "event" (or any changed part of it) from localStorage.